# (Qt/iOS) static plugin for module "QtQuick" with name "QtQuick2Plugin" cannot be loaded

Tags: c++, ios, qt, qml

I have a Qt/QML application that works perfectly on Android and Desktop and now I'm trying to port it to iOS.

When I execute it I get this error:

`static plugin for module "QtQuick" with name "QtQuick2Plugin" cannot be loaded: Namespace 'QtQuick' has already been used for type registration`

I have tried a lot of workarrounds:
https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-28357?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel
https://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/33667

But nothing works... Any idea?

Comment: have you work it out?

Comment: Unfortunately no, I'm still having the same problem